# How do I add AndEngine documentation in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, andengine, eclipse

I am very new to AndEngine. I have just downloaded the full documentation file, but I can't attach it to Eclipse. How can I do that?

Comment: Where did you get the documentation? As far as I know, there isn't any.

Comment: @JohnEye i just download all packages detail html pages with index.

Comment: Really? Does it contain any useful documentation or is it just an automatically generated "empty" JavaDoc? Also, could you please share the link with us?

Comment: @JohnEye: Almost i am wrong. it is jsut empty Java doc,contains all package definition only.

Comment: Oh, that's the one I've seen. I almost got my hopes up...

Comment: @JohnEye: how i get images from [link](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/#hg%2Fext%2Fimg)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6155/discussion-between-shihab-returns-and-johneye)

Answer (score 1):

Here is detailed how-to: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarjavadoc

Answer (score 0):

Please use this Andengine extension. This project comes with java documentations for many of the importatnt andengine functions. Its very useful. Plus you can join to update the docs. Checkout here :

```
https://github.com/digitalheir/AndEngine.git
```

Comment: thanks mate for reply...Is it andengine class extension for devlopment or only document file?

Comment: it is forked from AndEngine only but with documentation. You can always generate javadoc out of it.